# Java synchronized block vs concurrentHashMap vs Collections.synchronizedMap

Tags: java, synchronization

Say If have a synchronized method and within that method, I update a hashmap like this:

```
public synchronized void method1()
{
    myHashMap.clear();
    //populate the hashmap, takes about 5 seconds.
}
```

now while the method1 is running and the hashmap is being re-populated, if there are other threads tring to get the value of the hashmap, I assume they will get blocked?

Now instead of using sync method, if I change hashmap to ConcurrentHashMap like below, what's the behaviour?

```
public void method1()
{
     myConcurrentHashMap.clear();
    //populate the hashmap, takes about 5 seconds.
}
```

what if i use Collections.synchronizedMap ? is it the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have all read and write actions to your `HashMap` synchronized, you need to put the `synchronize` on all methods accessing the `HashMap`; it is not enough to block just one method.

`ConcurrentHashMap` allows thread-safe access to your data without locking. That means you can add/remove values in one thread and at the same time get values out in another thread without running into an exception. See also the [documentation of ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: if my another thread is trying to get all the values in that hashmap, not just some values of the map, how does that work?

Comment: You have to block the HashMap for all other threads. This means you have to put a `synchronized` not only on the method where you retrieve values from the map, but also on all other methods reading of modifying the map. Otherwise you might get a `ConcurrentModificationException` when you iterate over the map. You can get all entries of the map by calling the entrySet() method and iterating over the resulting set.

Comment: @Anna You did not explain the case if `Collections.synchronizedMap` is used.

Answer (score 15):

CHM(ConcurrentHashMap), instead of synchronizing every method on a common lock, restricting access to a single thread
at a time, it uses a finer-grained locking mechanism called lock striping  to allow a greater degree of shared access. Arbitrarily many reading threads
can access the map concurrently, readers can access the map concurrently with
writers, and a limited number of writers can modify the map concurrently. The result
is far higher throughput under concurrent access, with little performance penalty for
single-threaded access.
ConcurrentHashMap, along with the other concurrent collections, further improve on
the synchronized collection classes by providing iterators that do not throw
ConcurrentModificationException, thus eliminating the need to lock the collection
during iteration.

**As with all improvements, there are still a few tradeoffs.** The semantics of methods
that operate on the entire Map, such as size and isEmpty, have been slightly
weakened to reflect the concurrent nature of the collection. Since the result of size
could be out of date by the time it is computed, it is really only an estimate, so size
is allowed to return an approximation instead of an exact count. While at first this
may seem disturbing, in reality methods like size and isEmpty are far less useful in
concurrent environments because these quantities are moving targets.

Secondly, `Collections.synchronizedMap`

It's just simple HashMap with synchronized methods - I'd call it deprecated dute to CHM

Answer (score 0):

you could probably do

```
volatile private HashMap map = newMap();

private HashMap newMap() {
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    //populate the hashmap, takes about 5 seconds
    return map;
}

public void updateMap() {
    map = newMap();
}
```

A reader sees a constant map, so reads don't require synchronization, and are not blocked.

Comment: that's interesting. by using volatile, do they always see the 'whole' map of partial of it?

Comment: you create a whole map, then assign it to the volatile variable. after that, readers see the whole map.

Comment: The volatile only deals with the visibility of the map reference between threads. The code above DOES require syncronization if the map is to be accessed by different threads, concurrently and safely. This does not have similar effects to synchronized collection wrappers nor ConcurrentHashMap, as the question mentions.